# ACF - Adding PHP into Slick Slider Breaks the Slider

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have built a slider using Slick and now when I add a ACF options value into the slider it breaks. Any Ideas why? Just repeated the element for testing reasons.

Anyone had something similar?

So when I say its broken. You can add text in where it says the_field and it works so it displays the slider on screen. When you add the php the_field it cuts half the slide off and then shows the bottom part of the item.

So example the image below is how its displaying with the PHP Code so its displaying diffrently to how it should Next image below.

[image: Slider with Error]
[image: What it should look like]

```
<div class="service_slider">
<div class="item">
    <div class="col s12 m7 l7 pad0">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="/images/temp.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m5 l5 pad0">
        <?php the_field('title_resin', 'options'); ?>
        <p><a href="#">Find Out More</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col s12 m7 l7 pad0">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="/images/temp.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m5 l5 pad0">
        <?php the_field('title_resin', 'options'); ?>
        <p><a href="#">Find Out More</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col s12 m7 l7 pad0">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="/images/temp.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m5 l5 pad0">
        <?php the_field('title_resin', 'options'); ?>
        <p><a href="#">Find Out More</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col s12 m7 l7 pad0">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="/images/temp.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m5 l5 pad0">
        <?php the_field('title_resin', 'options'); ?>
        <p><a href="#">Find Out More</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col s12 m7 l7 pad0">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="/images/temp.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m5 l5 pad0">
        <?php the_field('title_resin', 'options'); ?>
        <p><a href="#">Find Out More</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.service_slider').slick({
            //dots: true,
            autoplay: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 3000,
            //fade: true,
            cssEase: 'linear',
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            vertical: true,
            prevArrow: '<button class="slick-prev slick-arrow" type="button" style="display: block;"><span></span></button>',
            nextArrow: '<button class="slick-next slick-arrow" type="button" style="display: block;"><span></span></button>',
        });
});
```

Comment: When you say it's broken, can you be more specific about how it's broken? Keep in mind it's unlikely WordPress knowledge will be of help here, it's probably going to require Slick JS Slider knowledge/help, possibly ACF specific help

Comment: @TomJNowell I have updated the post with some Images and what the issue is. Thought it copied across.

Comment: can you try `echo get_field()` instead of `the_field()`?

Comment: @rudtek Nope still having the same effect.

Comment: What type of field is title_resin? Is it just a text field, a textarea? a WYSIWYG? something else?